# SQL Developer - Retaining data values when exporting data

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I'm running a query on a table that has a `VARCHAR2` column with alphanumeric values (Ex. 234E0971, 2560D1A3, 38BC912E).

When I export the selected data into Excel, some of the values in that column are converted to scientific notation and when I change it back to a text it is a different value than what it originally was in the data table. For example, '282845E5' becomes '2.83E+10' in the exported Excel file and when its format is converted it is '28284500000'.

This doesn't happen for every value in that column, only some of them, but it's enough to be a problem.

Does anyone know why this is happening or what I can do to prevent it from happening?

Comment: I found a pretty decent way around this for anyone who's interested. I concatenated the problem column with a negligible text string, in my case '. For people with a similar problem, this might not be ideal if you can't have any additional text in the cells containing the values you want, in Excel. But if you just need to be able to see the values, it's a great fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.

**1st way**

Concatenate the column with `'` (quote) as the prefix and then export to your spreadsheet.

eg:

```
update table_name
set column_name = ''''||column_name
```

**2 way**

write a select query as below, then right click the grid and select `Save AS` to clipboard and paste in your excel spreadsheet.

eg:

```
select ''''|| column_name as column_name from table_name
```